# nhibernate and mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, phpmyadmin

I have an error with this code and I don't know why.

My code is composed of two files:

1. `systemprop.cs`
2. `System.hbm.xml`

But I have the following error:

> Erreur de syntaxe près de '[propertyID] as column1_19_, systemprop0_.[value] as column2_19_, systemprop0_.[' à la ligne 1"

which means that I have a syntax error near `'[propertyID] as column1_19_, systemprop0_.[value] as column2_19_, systemprop0_.['`, at line 1.

---

Here's my code:

**class `Systemprop`:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using DATA;

namespace DATA
{
    public partial class Systemprop
    {
        private string PropertyID  { set; get; }
        private string Value        { set; get; }
        private string Description   { set; get; }
        private int LastUpdateTime     { set; get; }
        private int CreationTime    { set; get; }
        // public Systemprop() { }

        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            if (SessionFactory == null)
            {
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
                config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect");
                config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver");

                config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "Server=localhost;Database=opengts;Uid=root;Pwd=;");
                config.AddAssembly("DATA");

                SessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
        public static IList<Systemprop> GetSystemprop()
        {
            using (ISession session = OpenSession())
            {
                if (session != null)
                {
                    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Systemprop");
                    IList<Systemprop> pets = query.List<Systemprop>();
                    return pets;
                }
            }

            return null;    
        }
    }
}
```

**`Systemprop.hbm.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="DATA" assembly="DATA">
    <class name="Systemprop" table="[dbo].[systemprops]" >
        <id name="PropertyID" column="[propertyID]" type="String" length="32" >
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="Value" column="[value]" type="String" not-null="false" length="16" /> 
        <property name="Description" column="[description]" type="String" not-null="false" length="128" /> 
        <property name="LastUpdateTime" column="[lastUpdateTime]" type="Int32" not-null="false" /> 
        <property name="CreationTime" column="[creationTime]" type="Int32" not-null="false" /> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But I have this error:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Erreur de syntaxe près de '[propertyID] as column1_19_, systemprop0_.[value] as column2_19_, systemprop0_.[' à la ligne 1]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +277
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId) +73
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId) +20
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +100
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +742
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1620
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +4
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +292
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) +244
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +186
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +129
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +116

[GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ select systemprop0_.[propertyID] as column1_19_, systemprop0_.[value] as column2_19_, systemprop0_.[description] as column3_19_, systemprop0_.[lastUpdateTime] as column4_19_, systemprop0_.[creationTime] as column5_19_ from [dbo].[systemprops] systemprop0_ ]
[SQL: select systemprop0_.[propertyID] as column1_19_, systemprop0_.[value] as column2_19_, systemprop0_.[description] as column3_19_, systemprop0_.[lastUpdateTime] as column4_19_, systemprop0_.[creationTime] as column5_19_ from [dbo].[systemprops] systemprop0_]]
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +213
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +18
   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) +79
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +51
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +231
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results) +369
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(String query, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) +317
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(String query, QueryParameters parameters) +282
   NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl.List() +163
   DATA.SystempropExtensions.GetSystemprop() in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\our_project\DATA\Queries\Systemprop.cs:37
   MvcApplication7.Controllers.AccueilController.Index() in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\our_project\MvcApplication7\Controllers\AccueilController.cs:16
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out all of the brackets and the `dbo` from your mapping document. Just use the table and column names as you would enter them in the database. Then give it a try.

Comment: i changed my xml file like that :

   <class name="Systemprop" table="[dbo].[systemprops]" >
            <id name="PropertyID" column="[propertyID]" >
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="Value" column="[value]"  /> 
            <property name="Description" column="[description]"  /> 
            <property name="LastUpdateTime" column="[lastUpdateTime]" /> 
            <property name="CreationTime" column="[creationTime]" /> 
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
but the same error is repeated

Comment: I'm saying remove all of the `[` and `]` from your mapping. I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Just click the check mark to the left of my answer. It will turn green. Thanks!

Comment: i am a beginner i don't have 15 reputaion so i can't sorry

Comment: You can accept another person's answer--you just can't accept your own :-)

Comment: but you make comments not answer so how can i do this?

Comment: It's that one at the top of these comments, that says: "Take out all of the brackets and the dbo from your mapping document. Just use the table and column names as you would enter them in the database. Then give it a try."